# Why don't objects have hasattr and getattr as attributes?

Tags: python, class

When you need to access an object's attributes dynamically in Python, you can just use the builtin functions `hasattr(object, attribute)` or `getattr(object, attribute)`.

However this seems like an odd order for the syntax to take. It's less readable and intuitive as it messes up the regular sentence structure for English.

> `if hasattr(person, age):`
>   if has attribute Person age

Where having it as a method of the object would be much more readable:

> `if person.hasattr(age):`
>   if Person has attribute age

Is there a particular reason for not implementing it this way? I could imagine there are cases where you're not sure if the object is even a proper object, rather than just `None`, but surely in those cases of uncertainty you could just use the builtin function anyway for extra safety.

Is there some other drawback or consideration I'm not thinking of that makes adding these not worth it?

Comment: On dynamically typed languages there is never certainty of the type of an object.

Comment: 1) Python isn't particularly *trying* to emulate English. 2) One less pretty obvious method name you could use for yourself. 3) There shall be one and only one obvious way to do it. *"If [special requirements] then [do it another way]"* is something Python tries to avoid.

Comment: @imreal Why is type relevant? All objects have to have/inherit `__getattr__` implemented for the builtin function to work anyway, so either approach requires that a function exist.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure if it was PEP0008 or the docs, but I could've sworn I saw an official Python source saying that it was designed to be readable like English because that makes it easier to use. I agree your other two points are good.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan `__getattr__` is not meant to be called directly. The advantage of free functions is that when they change they don't have to be reimplemented in every class. Which is great when the algorithm is type independent. You could if you wanted overwrite a built in function by deleting it. Still, I think it is a good question, I am not sure of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find quite a few similar examples - like `len(obj)` instead of `obj.length()`, `hash(obj)` instead of `obj.hash()`, `isinstance(obj, cls)` instead of `obj.isinstance(cls)`. You may also have noticed that addition is spelled `obj1 + obj2` instead of `obj1.add(obj2)`, substraction spelled `obj1 - obj2` instead of `obj1.sub(obj2)` etc...  The point is that some builtin "functions" are to be considered as operators rather than really functions, and are supported by "__magic__" methods (`__len__`, `__hash__`, `__add__` etc).

As of the "why", you'd have to ask GvR but historical reasons set asides, it at least avoids a lot of namespace pollution / name clashes. How would you name the length of a "Line" or "Rectangle" class if `length` was already a "kind of but not explicitely reserved" name ? And how should introspection understand that `Rectangle.length()` doesn't mean `Rectangle` is a sizeable sequence-like object ?

Using generic "operator" functions (note that proper operators also exist as functions, cf the `operator` module) + "__magic__" methods make the intention clear and leaves normal names open for "user space" semantic.

wrt/ the "regular sentence structure for English", I have to say I don't really care - the very first programming language I learned was Apple's hyperscript (which later became applescript) and I quickly found it rather uselessly verbose .

> I could imagine there are cases where you're not sure if the object is
>   even a proper object, rather than just None

`None` *is* a "proper" object. Everything in Python (well, everything you can bind to a name) is a "proper" object.

Answer (score 1):

Its part of the language design. I guess your find some docs about the more complicated thoughts behind it, but the key points are like

- You suggest to use a function of an object for a builtin function on all objects. Why should this function be specific to this object?
- Semantics: the `getattr` function works on objects, not as part of an object.
- Namespace: The functions of an object are defined by you, not by the language. Internal functions are of the form `__getattr__` and you will find this function on your object ;-). And getattr uses it internally, so you can even override it (if you know, what you're doing).